# Call java command line program from .net and return output of STDOUT to variable

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a java command line program I need execute from within a .net program(VB)

The java command line program spits out a number when it's done executing that I need to know.

Can I take the STDOUT from the java program and read it into the .net program?

EDIT: I've got the program executing, but how do I read the inputstream?

Here is the code for executing the java program

```
Dim processinfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
processinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\path\to\working\directory"
processinfo.FileName = "java.exe"
processinfo.Arguments = "-jar myprogram.jar argumentA argumentB"
Process.Start(processinfo)
```

This nets me a command box and I get to watch the program execute..

EDIT: full code sample that works

```
Dim processinfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
processinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
processinfo.FileName = "java.exe"
processinfo.Arguments = "-jar my.jar list of params"
Dim myProcess As New Process()
processinfo.UseShellExecute = False
processinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.StartInfo = processinfo
myProcess.Start()
Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
' Read the standard output of the spawned process. 
Dim myString As String
Do
    myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine()
TextBox1.Text += myString
Loop Until (myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
myProcess.WaitForExit()
myProcess.Close()
```

Comment: through, VB call "java javaprogram" as a process, and read the inputstream.

Comment: this has nothing to do with asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) (e.g., [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) among [other possibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader_methods.aspx)). Be sure to set [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to `false`, and [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to `true`.